# plotting points with different colors by name in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

how can different points be plotted in different colors in matplotlib when the colors are named and not referred to by number? eg

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
# this fails
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6],c=["r", "k", "b"])
```

`c` only takes numeric values. is there a way to pass it names of colors instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), in which case your code works:

```
plt.scatter([1,2,3],[4,5,6],c=["r", "k", "b"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
xx = [1, 2, 3]
yy = [4, 5, 6]
colors = ['r', 'k', 'b']
for ii in range(len(xx)):
    plt.plot(xx[ii], yy[ii], 'o', color=colors[ii])
```